# How to calculate factorial in c++

Tags: c++

**Calculate factorials in C++ by function** 

I wrote this code :

```
int fact (int A)
{
int B ;
B= A*(A-1);
return B;
}
```

```
  int main ()
{
    int x;
    cout <<"Enter number to calulate its factorial :"<<endl;
        cin >> x ;
        cout << fac (x);

}
```

Comment: Your `fact(10)` results as `10 * 9`, that's it. Use recursion or a loop to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to google it before posting there?

```
int factorial(int n) 
{
    if (n < 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return !n ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fact function just computes factorial for one time. You should do something resursively like:

```
int fact (int A)
{
     if (A <= 1) {
         return 1;
     }
     return A*fact(A-1);
}
```

or if you want it in iterative way then you should do the following:

```
int fact (int A)
{
    int B = 1, i = 2;
    for (; i<=A; i++) {
        B = B*i;
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably limit the range to unsigned integers, considering the standard factorial is limited to non-negative numbers.

Comment: @Mario I would agree with you 100%.. I just tried to rectify code that OP had so he has some basic understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

And why din't you search it instead.

anyway...

```
int n, count;
    unsigned long long int factorial=1;         
    cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
    cin>>n;
    if ( n< 0)
        printf("Error!!! Factorial of negative number doesn't exist.");
    else
    {
       for(count=1;count<=n;++count)    /* for loop terminates if count>n */
       {
          factorial*=count;              /* factorial=factorial*count */
       }
    cout<<factorial;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this has nothing to do with C++ ( as your question says ). This is specific to alogorithms and they can be employed in any language.

You can use below example for your reference.

```
int fact (int A)
{
     if (A == 0) {
         return 1;
     }
     return A*fact(A-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial (int a) {
    return a==0 ? 1 : a*factorial(a-1); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using C++ rather than C, I'd simply go with a template function. Bonus for this: due to expansion/implementation at compile time, your code will be highly optimized and essentially as fixed as possible with little to no overhead:

```
// First the generic template for pretty much all numbers
template <unsigned int X>
unsigned int factorial() {
    return X * factorial<X - 1>();
}

// Now the specialization for the special case of 0
template <>
unsigned int factorial<0>() {
    return 1;
}
```

For example, to calculate the factorial of 5, you'd just call `factorial<5>()`. With optimizations enabled, this will result in just `120`. Unfortunately this is not possible with dynamic variables.

Comment: I'm not sure it is useful or appropriate, because an optimizing compiler would be able to transform the recursive (or the iterative) `fact` function -by constant folding and inlining- into a constant when its argument is constant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, it probably just depends on the level of optimization. At maximum, there might not be any difference at all whether you use a template or not.

Comment: No, at least on GCC optimization does not depend if you use templates or not (since template expansion happens before optimization). So I downvote your answer.